# Inserting moment to google plus with google-api-dotnet-client WP8 error 401

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to add a moment from a windows phone application for two days now and I can't get it work. There is no real tutorial or what so ever to do it... Anyway, from various sources I got so far that I can login, request scopes ( even though the login.plus scope isn't requested for some reason) and I try to post a moment. This is the code I was able to create

```
List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
        scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");    
        scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "<My client ID>",
                ClientSecret = "<My Client Secret>"
            },
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

        var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "WP Drive Sample Application",
        };

        var plusService = new PlusService(initializer);

        Moment body = new Moment();
        ItemScope target = new ItemScope();
        target.Id = "<Unique ID>";
        target.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png";
        target.Type = "";
        target.Description = "The description for the activity";
        target.Name = "An example of add activity";

        body.Target = target;
        body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

        MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
            new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
                plusService,
                body,
                "me",
                MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault);
        Moment wrote = await insert.ExecuteAsync();
```

And I get this error when I try to use the insert.ExecuteAsync();

```
    {The service plus has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Unauthorized [401]
Errors [
    Message[Unauthorized] Location[ - ] Reason[unauthorized] Domain[global]
]

   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at GooglePlus.MainPage.<Test>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)}
```

After some search I found out that probably the problem why I can't access it, is that I don't use request_visible_actions. But the problem is that I have no idea how to request it with my code and I couldn't found any resource on the internet in c sharp, which I could  use in my windows phone application. Any idea how can I fix this issue and be able to finally post a moment from my application?

Comment: Did you check out that link: http://ikaisays.com/2013/07/19/debugging-your-google-oauth-2-0-token-when-you-get-http-401s-or-403s/. In my opinion you didn't enable the API.

Comment: I have Google+ API enabled

Comment: Didn't solved it. Looked into it for a while, but couldn't find a solution so I abandoned it. When I'll have time I'll try to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. Your email scope is incorrect, this has recently been updated to "email"
2. The 401 is happening because you're missing the request_visible_actions for writing app activities.

For 2, you can either use the Google+ Sign-In button to perform the authorization request or you can alter the request URI to push in the additional parameter. The following shows how to create the Sign-In button with request_visible_actions set:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

The callback from the Sign-In button returns an authorization code that you can exchange for  access/refresh tokens and can then use for making API calls to write app activities to Google. Because you're using Windows Phone, I'm less sure how this should work.

At any rate, the KEY missing portion is most likely the requestvisibleactions value. If you are missing request_visible_actions, your consent dialog will look like:

[image: Incorrect example with only sign-in]

To verify it's requesting the correct permissions, you will see a consent dialog containing the following:

[image: Correct example]

If the user is being prompted for app activities, you are setting your scopes correctly, and should have permissions.

If you are requesting the correct scopes but your project is missing the appropriate APIs (Google+ API in the [Google developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)), you will continue to see 401 errors - make sure you have added Google+.

I have now created a console project demonstrating [how to request the Google+ app activity types this from native apps](https://github.com/gguuss/google-dotnet-demo) - check the

There is a known bug where after you have authorize the user without the app activity permissions, you must [disconnect and reconnect the app](https://plus.google.com/apps) in order to be granted the permission.

Comment: As I said in my question, I already thought that my problem is that I need that request_visible_actions parameter, and I said already that the scope isn't coming up when prompting permission. I already considered using the sign in button, but that's not really an option for me, because I would like to have a similar feeling, like my other sharing options(plus I don't even know if I could use it ). My problem is that to render HTML I can only use WebBrowser component. So to render the sign button I would need to create a html, somehow listen for request changes etc... It's seems overkill.

Comment: Acknowledged, still looking into this further.

Comment: @class Do you have the "response_type" parameter set to "code"?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Thanks for the nudge. I'll take a look at this as soon as I can. The button needs data-accesstype="offline"

Comment: @G.T. did you manage to resolve this issue, i am having same problem. Searched all over internet. Can you please post your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just gave up on posting to google+. When I'll have time I'll try to do it again and come back if there is any update.